# Issue with NETMF Nuget - This partUri is already contained in the package

Tags: nuget, .net-micro-framework

I'm struggling to build a nuget package for a .NET MicroFramework project.

This is my nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>WildernessLabs.Netduino.Foundation</id>
    <title>Netduino.Foundation</title>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <authors>Bryan Costanich, Frank Krueger, Craig Dunn</authors>
    <owners>Wilderness Labs</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/WildernessLabs/Netduino.Foundation/blob/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/WildernessLabs/Netduino.Foundation</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Netduino.Foundation greatly simplifies the task of building complex .NET Microframework (MF) powered connected things with Netduino.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017 Wilderness Labs</copyright>
    <tags>NETMF Netduino</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin/Release/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
    <file src="bin/Release/le/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
    <file src="bin/Release/be/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
  </files>
</package>
```

It's sitting in the same folder as my `.csproj` file. When I run `nuget pack Netduino.Foundation.nuspec -verbosity detailed`, I get the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: This partUri is already contained in the package`

The only thing I can think of here is that the `bin`, `/be`, and `/le` folders include `Netduino.Foundation.dll`, but in examining [other NETMF .nuspec files](https://bitbucket.org/aalmada/hydramf/src/6b8989ce12837598a10cfccae3828ece7452d9df/HydraMF.Hardware.Netduino/HydraMF.Hardware.Netduino.nuspec?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Need to make sure the target for files have unique folders, so this:

```
<file src="bin/Release/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
<file src="bin/Release/le/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
<file src="bin/Release/be/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf" />
```

becomes:

```
<file src="bin/Release/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf43/" />
<file src="bin/Release/le/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf43/le" />
<file src="bin/Release/be/Netduino.Foundation.*" target="lib/netmf43/be" />
```